# Classification with partially censored class information

Tags: classification, censoring

I'd like to build a classifier for my widgets! Here is my data:

| Class | Feature 1 | Feature 2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [1,5] | 0.1 | "E" | ... |
| 4 | 1.7 | "B" | ... |
| [2,3,5] | 0.8 | "D" | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I.e., for some observations I only know that they belong to one class within a subset of the 5 possible class labels, but I don't know exactly which class they belong to.

Does anyone know a principled way to approach this problem? Ideally, the solution would be a [probabilistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_classification) [multiclass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification) classifier that effectively incorporates this partially censored class information.

One approach I've considered is to split unknown classes into weighted observations, i.e., transforming the above dataset into:

| Class | Weight | Feature 1 | Feature 2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.5 | 0.1 | "E" | ... |
| 5 | 0.5 | 0.1 | "E" | ... |
| 4 | 1 | 1.7 | "B" | ... |
| 2 | 0.33 | 0.8 | "D" | ... |
| 3 | 0.33 | 0.8 | "D" | ... |
| 5 | 0.33 | 0.8 | "D" | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

This seems like it could lead to reasonable outputs, but I'd love to know if a cleaner solution exists! Appreciate any insights you might have.

Comment: Try semi-supervised methods.